# SQL UNION don't work with multiupdate how to make that work

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE books,item,orders
SET books.quantity=books.quantity-item.quantity
WHERE orders.client_id=6 AND orders.id=item.order_id AND books.id=item.item_id
UNION
UPDATE computers,item,orders
SET computers.quantity=computers.quantity-item.quantity
WHERE orders.client_id=6 AND orders.id=item.order_id AND computers.id=item.item_id
UNION
UPDATE smartphones,item,orders
SET smartphones.quantity=smartphones.quantity-item.quantity
WHERE orders.client_id=6 AND orders.id=item.order_id AND smartphones.id=item.item_id
UNION
UPDATE sound,item,orders
SET sound.quantity=sound.quantity-item.quantity
WHERE orders.client_id=6 AND orders.id=item.order_id AND sound.id=item.item_id
UNION
UPDATE vision,item,orders
SET vision.quantity=vision.quantity-item.quantity
WHERE orders.client_id=6 AND orders.id=item.order_id AND vision.id=item.item_id
```

Comment: for a start you cant use a union in an update, its only valid for select

Comment: Please explain your code and problem

Comment: You need to explain what issue youre facing

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following lines:
UPDATE (all the attributes you want to update)
SET (the new values)
FROM
(#here you can use the union for all your tables)
WHERE (conditions)

Hope this helps!